# Windows, Google Chrome - Renaming multiple files with same name

Tags: windows, chrome

As part of an automation process using Python Selenium, I'm downloading a number of files with the same name, and each one gets automatically renamed with the name followed by a number within brackets. To demonstrate with a file with name "test":

first file is named "test", second is named "test (1)" ...and so on until "test (100)"

Following this, newly downloaded files request a prompt to rename ie they don't get renamed automatically to "test (101)" etc.

Are there any settings, on either Win 7 or Google Chrome, to modify the limit on automatic file renaming?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need all 100+ files to be available at once?